# How can I check whether a port is open in cPanel on a shared hosting account?

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, port-number

I need to check if port `3000` is open because when I try to access `example.com:3000` I can't connect.

How can I check this for sure on cPanel taking into consideration I'm on a shared hosting account without root privileges?

Comment: If you can't connect, it could mean that the port isn't open, or it could mean that the service you're trying to connect to isn't properly running. What service is it, and are you sure that it's running properly on the server?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister It could also mean its only bound to localhost or there is a firewall in place.

Comment: I dont use cpanel, but if you can run php ehy not knock up a trivial page to do it (along the lines of the client example at https://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php )

Comment: Does your Cpanel allow you to ssh into it (as a user, I get you dont have root).  If so, you can still use telnet and/or netcat (nc) to do this.

Comment: Im trying to run node.js in fact when I start it on the terminal I get the success message but I cant access it on the browser since yesterday. I have SSH access though.

Comment: I tried this on the SSH terminal: nc -zv localhost 3000. I got this: `Ncat: Connected to ::1:80.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.`

Comment: @CainNuke It's highly unlikely on a shared hosting account that this port would be open, and would really be up to the hosting provider's firewall settings. Leaving non-default ports open might present possible security issues, but you can check with your hosting provider to confirm which ports they allow.

Comment: @CainNuke There are some ways to use Node.js on a shared account, but may or may not work with your specific provider - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777750/how-to-host-a-node-js-application-in-shared-hosting). Otherwise, you might consider upgrading to a VPS account which could allow you to have root access and open specific ports - check with your hosting provider first though to see if there are any restrictions.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way to check if a port is open on your own.  Have you tried asking your hosting companies tech support if you can use it?